Orientation of 1-manifolds with boundary in Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint
In the book, Milnor says that the orientation on each tangent space must be defined so that there is a neighborhood of each point and a chart $f$ from that neighborhood to $R^m$ or $H^m={(x_1,...,x_n)\in R^m|x_n\geq0}$ such that $df_x$ at any point in that neighborhood sends a corrected oriented basis of $TM_x$ to a correctly oriented basis of $R^m$ wrt the standard basis. But for a one-manifold, wouldn't an "outward-pointing" vector (as i understand it, one that is the image of a vector in $R^m$ with $x_n<0$) automatically be negatively oriented?

You’re confusing the $1$-manifold with boundary and its boundary. You have to define orientations on a $0$-dimensional manifold.

@TedShifrin I don't see any issue with the definition of orientation on a 0-manifold, my issue is how we can orient the tangent space of the 1-manifold at its boundary. Because there are two options for the basis upto magnitude, inward and outward, but I don't see how the outward tangent is an option since the chart should send this positively oriented basis to a positively oriented basis of R

If we allow charts at boundary points to be diffeomorphisms into $(-\infty,0]$ as well, then we can sidestep this problem. Is my thinking correct?

You orient $[a,b]$ headed to the right. The chart at $b$, i.e., a diffeomorphism from $(c,b]$ to $[0,s)$, is necessarily orientation-reversing since it must be given by a decreasing function. You’re right that this is a problem uniquely in dimension $1$. Someone raised this issue recently on this site.

I understand. Thanks!
